# An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name in strict mode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, strict

This is mye code:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { postReducers } from './postReducers';
import { stationsReducer } from './TrackCircuitSensorDataFormReducers/StationsReducer';
import { trackCircuitReducer } from './TrackCircuitSensorDataFormReducers/TrackCircuitReducer';

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    posts: postReducers,
    stationsReducer: stationsReducer,
    trackCircuitReducer, trackCircuitReducer
});

export type IApplicationState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
```

The line:

```
trackCircuitReducer, trackCircuitReducer
```

Gives me:

> (property) trackCircuitReducer: Reducer
>
> An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name
>   in strict mode.ts(1117)
>
> Duplicate identifier 'trackCircuitReducer'.ts(2300)

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is cus you are using comma instead of two dots
 **trackCircuitReducer, trackCircuitReducer**

Use this :

> trackCircuitReducer: trackCircuitReducer

Comment: It's unlikely that state should be littered with `*Reducer` keys, more likely it's supposed to be `{ posts: postReducers, stations: stationsReducer, trackCircuit: trackCircuitReducer }`.

Answer (score 2):

In an object all keys should be followed by a `:` to pass the value.

Change

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    posts: postReducers,
    stationsReducer: stationsReducer,
    trackCircuitReducer, trackCircuitReducer
});
```

to

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    posts: postReducers,
    stationsReducer: stationsReducer,
    trackCircuitReducer: trackCircuitReducer
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By having the typo `,` instead of `:`, you're using [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

So, your object literal is equivalent to:

```
{
    posts: postReducers,
    stationsReducer: stationsReducer,
    trackCircuitReducer: trackCircuitReducer,
    trackCircuitReducer: trackCircuitReducer,
}
```

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode):

> Strict mode prior to Gecko 34 requires that all properties named in an object literal be unique. The normal code may duplicate property names, with the last one determining the property's value. But since only the last one does anything, the duplication is simply a vector for bugs, if the code is modified to change the property value other than by changing the last instance. Duplicate property names are a syntax error in strict mode.

(Note: This is no longer the case in [ECMAScript 2015](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1041128))

You can simplify your literal to:

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    posts: postReducers,
    stationsReducer,
    trackCircuitReducer
})
```